# How to make form html for updateview

Tags: python, html, django

I was making my own forms for CreateView and UpdateView with my html file because I don't want to display the form like this {{form.as_p}}.

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Post

class PostCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('title', 'cover', 'text',)
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'title'}),
            'cover': forms.FileInput(attrs={'class': 'image'}),
            'text': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'text'})
        }

class PostDeleteForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ('__all__')
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import generic
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostCreationForm, PostDeleteForm

class PostListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_view = 'post_list'
    template_name = 'forum/post_list.html'


class PostDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    context_object_view = 'post'
    template_name = 'forum/post_detail.html'

class PostCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Post
    form_class = PostCreationForm
    template_name = 'forum/post_create.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save(commit = False)
            response.author = self.request.user
            response.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(response.id)]))


class PostUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Post
    context_object_view = 'post'
    form_class = PostCreationForm
    template_name = 'forum/post_edit.html'

    def get_post(self, pk):
        return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        if form.is_valid():
            response = form.save(commit = False)
            response.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('post_detail', args=[str(response.id)]))


class PostDeleteView(generic.DeleteView):
    model = Post
    context_object_view = 'post'
    form_class = PostDeleteForm
    template_name = 'forum/post_delete.html'
    success_url = '/'

    def get_post(self, pk):
        return get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
```

post_create.html

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% block css %}
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/post_create.css' %}">
{% endblock css %}

{% block title %}Questions{% endblock title %}

{% block content %}

<h1 class="m-title">New Post</h1>

<div class="form">
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id='postform'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <p class="n-title"><label for="id_title">Title: </label></p>
        <input id="id_title" type="text" name="title" class="title" maxlength="40" required>

        <p class="n-image"><label for="id_cover">Image: </label></p>
        <input id="id_cover" type="file" name="cover" class="image" required>

        <p class="n-text"><label for="id_text">Text: </label></p>
        <textarea id="id_text" placeholder="Enter your text here" name="text" class="text" form='postform' required></textarea>
        <button class="btn btn-success" id="button" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

And I also wanted to do for the UpdateView, but I don't know how to make the input fields display the current value of the post (title, text). The html file is the same as for CreateView. How do I make the input display the current value of the post that is being modified?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to be manually writing the html for the form like that.

If you must, you can pass in value like:

```
<input id="id_title" type="text" name="title" class="title" maxlength="40" value="{{ form.title.value }}" required>
```

Better would be to render the field using django so that your form field attributes like maxlength and required match your form class specification. For example, this will create the input for your title field:

{{ form.title }}

If you want more flexibility in styling look at [crispy-forms](https://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or my preference [floppyforms](https://django-floppyforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)